# Is the comma correct in the following news title or should I leave it out?

Tags: commas, titles

***This Is Why Statistics Matter, and It's Why You Should Care***

Comment: There are no grammar rules for writing headlines. They are very far removed from human language.

Comment: Personally, I'd leave out "This Is..," the comma, and "...It's".

Comment: Thanks, John and Oldbag. The information helps a lot.